# "pc" variant of McEliece—what is it?

Tags: history, mceliece

It looks like the IETF draft specification of Classic McEliece has [penciled in separate variants of the algorithm](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-josefsson-mceliece-00.html#name-selected-parameter-sets) for so-called "pc" and "non-pc" variants (as well as the familiar "f" and non-"f" variants); presumably they're going to be assigned separate OIDs for X.509/CMS/PKCS#8/related `AlgorithmIdentifier` use.

These "pc" and "non-pc" variants are described in [this PDF from classic.mceliece.org](https://classic.mceliece.org/iso-mceliece-20230419.pdf) (excerpted below), but they are, disturbingly, not present in [the reference implementation](https://classic.mceliece.org/nist/mceliece-20221023.tar.gz) or [the specification itself](https://classic.mceliece.org/mceliece-spec-20221023.pdf). (I was [unable to find](https://www.google.com/search?q=mceliece+%22pc%22+vs+%22non-pc%22+parameter+set) any information about the development or rationale of these variants.)

I understand the point of the "f" variants (faster but with more convoluted key generation code), and they *are* explicitly stated to be interoperable with the non-"f" variants. But I can't find anywhere **either** the rationale or interoperability status of the "pc" vs "non-pc" variant.

Are they, like the "f" variants, interoperable with their counterparts?

Most importantly: What is the purpose of this variant? What are the trade-offs? When was it introduced? Where did it come from?

---

> #### For non-pc parameter sets:
>
> A ciphertext $C$ is an element of $\mathbb{F}_{2^{mt}}$. It is represented as a $\lceil m t / 8\rceil$ byte string.
>
> There are two types of hash inputs: $(1, v, C)$ and $(0, v, C)$. Here $v \in \mathbb{F}_{2^n}$, and $C$ is a ciphertext. The initial $0$ or $1$ is represented as a byte. The vector $v$ is represented as the next $\lceil n / 8 \rceil$ bytes. The ciphertext, if present, is represented as the next $\lceil m t / 8 \rceil$ bytes. All hash inputs thus begin with byte $0$ or $1$, as mentioned earlier.
>
> #### For pc parameter sets:
>
> A ciphertext $C$ has two components: $C_0 \in \mathbb{F}_{2^{mt}}$ and $C_1 \in \mathbb{F}_{2^\ell}$. The ciphertext is represented as the concatenation of the $\lceil m t / 8\rceil$-byte string representing $C_0$ and the $\lceil \ell / 8 \rceil$-byte string representing $C_1$.
>
> There are three types of hash inputs: $(2, v)$; $(1, v, C)$; and $(0, v, C)$. Here $v \in \mathbb{F}_{2^n}$, and $C$ is a ciphertext. The initial $0$, $1$, or $2$ is represented as a byte. The vector $v$ is represented as the next $\lceil n / 8 \rceil$ bytes. The ciphertext, if present, is represented as the next $\lceil m t / 8 \rceil + \lceil \ell / 8 \rceil$ bytes. All hash inputs thus begin with bytes $0$, $1$, or $2$, as mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the so-called "Plaintext Confirmation" variant, and indeed it was submitted as "the" algorithm in rounds 1–3 of the competition, but was replaced in round 4 with a simpler version that has a shorter ciphertext, because the security features it provides were not strongly valued by the competition judges.

Classic McEliece "pc" is a [now-alternate version of the algorithm](https://classic.mceliece.org/mceliece-pc-20221023.pdf) engineered to keep the cryptosystem secure in [these circumstances](https://classic.mceliece.org/mceliece-security-20221023.pdf#subsection.6.5):

> 1. Some decapsulation queries occur.
> 2. Then, a single bit is flipped at a random position in a stored private key (either [by nature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-event_upset) or [by an attacker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_hammer)).
> 3. Then, further decapsulation queries occur against the modified private key.

To lay out the differences more clearly than in the question:

- The "round-4" (or "non-pc", or now "regular") version of the algorithm outputs $C := {{({ I \, \vert \, pk })}e}$ as the KEM ciphertext.
- The "pc" (or "round-3") version of the algorithm outputs $C := { {{({I \, \vert \, pk})}e} \; \Vert \; {H{({2 \; \Vert \; e})}} }$ as the KEM ciphertext.
- Both algorithms use the same formula, $K := H{({ \text{1} \; \Vert \; e \; \Vert \; C })}$, to derive the shared secret from the ciphertext.

You can clearly see here that the ciphertext has an extra glob, $H{({2 \; \Vert \; e})}$, just appended to it, inflating the ciphertext by 32 bytes — or around 15%–20% — with the $\text{SHAKE256}$ algorithm.

(Notation: $pk$ is the public key, $e$ is a random error vector of fixed weight generated according to the parameters, $I$ is the identity matrix of appropriate size for the given multiplication, $\Vert$ is octet string concatenation, $1$ and $2$ are single octets of their respective values, $\vert$ is [matrix augmentation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2506183/188128), and $H$ is the hash function chosen in the parameters.)

And, of course, this is *not* interoperable with the non-pc variant.